# FSharp.Data Csv.Load() failed with Only web locations are supported

Tags: f#, f#-data

I have the following code:

```
#r "../packages/FSharp.Data.2.0.9/lib/portable-net40+sl5+wp8+win8/FSharp.Data.dll"

open FSharp.Data

let trainData = CsvFile.Load("../resources/Train.csv")
let rowCount = trainData.Rows |> Seq.length
```

And I am getting this exception

```
System.Exception: Only web locations are supported
```

I am using VS2012.  Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I changed it to

```
#r "../packages/FSharp.Data.2.0.9/lib/net40/FSharp.Data.dll"
```

and it worked

Hope this helps someone

Comment: Yes, portable profiles do not support the file system. Improved the error message: https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data/commit/6356db5a0c483cefa0c83f3e5eeb78faf21416a0