# F# CSV Provider type mismatch

Tags: csv, f#, analytics, type-providers, f#-data

I'm having an issue with the F# CSV Type provider and getting a type mismatch.  I'm new to F#, so it very well could be a basic issue.  I have put the file up on blob storage so you can replicate easier. https://analyzethis.blob.core.windows.net/voterinfo/WakeCountyVoterCSV 
note: you will need to change the providers file location to your download location to replicate exactly.  You may be able to load dynamically from blob as well.

The error I get is:

Type mismatch: Expecting a seq< CsvProvider<...>.Row> -> int

but given a

seq< CsvProvider<...>.Row> -> unit

Type int does not match unit

code:

```
open FSharp.Data
type voterType = CsvProvider<"C:\\Users\\dacrook\\Documents\\vrdb\\VoterCSVData2.csv", AssumeMissingValues=true, MissingValues="">

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let voterData = voterType.Parse("C:\\Users\\dacrook\\Documents\\vrdb\\VoterCSVData2.csv")
    voterData.Rows |> Seq.iter(fun r -> printfn "%A" r)
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

~David

Comment: This is probably a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26080292/type-mismatch-works-in-f-interactive-but-not-in-a-real-f-project/26080298#26080298

Answer (score 2):

`main` has an expected return type of int so your last line of code in the `main` function needs to be an int expression

```
open FSharp.Data
type voterType = CsvProvider<"C:\\Users\\dacrook\\Documents\\vrdb\\VoterCSVData2.csv",   AssumeMissingValues=true, MissingValues="">

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let voterData = voterType.Parse("C:\\Users\\dacrook\\Documents\\vrdb\\VoterCSVData2.csv")
    voterData.Rows |> Seq.iter(fun r -> printfn "%A" r)
    0  // <--- Add an int as the return value
```

Comment: So I went ahead and added the 0, and readline like below, however it is not printing information about the rows.  Putting it in the interactive yields the output:

val it: unit= ()

Comment: I just realized .Parse() is for parsing string csv's that are passed in.  Load should be used for files and uri's.  Unfortunately when attempting to use .Load, it tells me only web locations are supported.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25449774/fsharp-data-csv-load-failed-with-only-web-locations-are-supported because I think it may be related?